# How would I add a collider to a line renderer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a noob trying to make a game like this https://youtu.be/qxwO1wyz50w?t=37 , but i cannot figure out how to add collision to my line renderers. Would a line renderer be the way to go about this or is there a better way?

Here is my code so far (messy I know im new to programming as well )

```
public GameObject crossHair;
public LineRenderer line;
public Transform startPoint;

public GameObject lazer;

void Start()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;

}

void Update()
{
    crossHair.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        LineSpawner();
        startPoint.position = crossHair.transform.position;
    }
}

void LineSpawner()
{
    
    Vector2 shootDir = crossHair.transform.position - startPoint.transform.position;
 
    GameObject lazerInstance = Instantiate(lazer);
    line = lazerInstance.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    line.SetPosition(0, startPoint.transform.position);
    line.SetPosition(1, crossHair.transform.position);


    Physics2D.Raycast(startPoint.transform.position, shootDir);
    Debug.DrawRay(startPoint.transform.position, shootDir, Color.red);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot add a collider component to line renderers but a way  around this is to create another gameobject that is invisible and make it a child of the line itself. What you then want to do is use the `invoke("targetFunctionName", amountOfSeconds)` method to destroy the collider gameobject after the player has hit it, this is so the game doesn't lag for those who are doing well while playing it. What you then want to do is add a physics material to the game object and set its bounciness property to max(which I think is 1). Do the same for the player's gameobject and you're done.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ill definitely try it out when i get the chance.

Comment: how would i scale the child game object to the length of my line renderer line?

Comment: you make the line renderer + invisible gameobject a prefab and it will automatically set its size.

Comment: i tried to make it a prefab with an empty game object and a box collider, but unfortunately the collider did not scale to the length of the line renderer. When i inspect the line renderer object it says that the scale doesnt change and remains its original transform and scale.

Comment: @pip what you need to do is draw the line renderer and make an empty gameobject and add a box collider to the empty gameobject then make the empty gameobject a child of the linerenderer gameobject. Set Its size to the line renderers size and width and length and so on. then with your script make it calculate the angle between the first point of your line and the second point. then make it set the empty gameobjects Z axis angle to that.